# my delete program doesn't work in php

Tags: php, mysql

My delete program doesn't work in php.

The following code displays the information, but the delete code doesn't work, where did I make mistakes?

The connection is established, but delete code is not working, why?

**connection.php**

```
<?php

// Database Connection
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","sathishcst","geni7joy");
mysql_select_db("practice",$con);
?>
```

**display.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
$query = "select * from pays";
$data = mysql_query($query);
?>
<html>

<body>
<table border=”1″ cellpadding=”5″>
<tr>
<th>Id</th> <th>NewsList</th> <th>Anchor link</th> <th colspan=”2″>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php while($rec = mysql_fetch_array($data)) { ?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $rec['id']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $rec['name']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $rec['email']; ?> </td>
<td> <a href=”edit.php?id=<?php echo $rec['id']; ?>”>edit</a> </td>
<td> <a onClick="return confirm('Sure to delete!')" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $rec['id']; ?>">delete</a> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
require_once “connect.php”;
$msg = “”;
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : “0″;
$query = “delete from tbemp where id=”.$id;
if(mysql_query($query)) {
header(“location:display.php”);
} else {
echo “unable to delete!”;
}
?>
```

Comment: When you say your code 'doesn't work', what exactly do you mean? Does it throw an error? Does it do anything?

Comment: Do you see the funky quotes `” ″` and `“”`? That's part of a big problem. Use regular quotes `"`. Having used error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have thrown you errors.

Comment: not to mention the single quotes around the php

Comment: Please, for the love of everything, DON'T USE GET REQUESTS (`delete.php?id=X`) FOR DESTRUCTIVE ACTIONS (or any "change" action).

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated please use msqli_*

Answer (score 0):

You made an error in `delete.php` file. After where clause, you need to use `$_REQUEST['id']` instead of `$id`

Try this code:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";
$msg = "";
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : "0";
$query = "delete from tbemp where id=".$_REQUEST['id'];
if(mysql_query($query)) {
header("location:display.php");
} else {
echo "unable to delete!";
}
?>
```

Comment: [Look at my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772727/my-delete-progame-doesnt-work-in-php#comment43956391_27772727) and the OP's code again very carefully.

Comment: So you made the quotes change. What about the rest of it? You've made no reference to that; only I did.

Comment: @Fred-ii, I changed this. I was just copying the Sathishkumar's code to give him answer.

Comment: It would still be good if you made a reference in your answer in regards to the funky quotes, should my comment ever get deleted. People visiting the question and answer will know where the faults/syntax errors were made. Plus, adding `exit;` after header is good also. Just trying to help and to improve the answer.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, its should be very usefull for me,

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<?php
require_once “connect.php”;
$msg = “”;
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : “0″;
$query = “delete from tbemp where id=”.$id;
if(mysql_query($query)) {
header(“location:display.php”);
} else {
echo “unable to delete!”;
}
?>
```

with this:

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";
$msg = "";
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : "0";
$query = "delete from tbemp where id=".$id;
if(mysql_query($query)) {
header("location:display.php");
} else {
echo "unable to delete!";
}
?>
```